# vb.net receiving response from a php script

Tags: php, vb.net

My application (written in vb.net) send data to a php script hosted on one of the free webhosting servers. The php script evaluates the data, and responds accordingly. The response from the server looks something like this:

```
Valid 
<!-- Hosting3322 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="theurlforthewebsite/count.php"></script>
<!-- End of Analytics Code -->
```

'Valid' is from my php script. Rest of is a little script by the server that they hide in every page.

Here is the php script:

```
<?php
$d = $_POST['mac'];
if($d=='45bgd0434')
 echo "Valid";
else 
 echo "Invalid";
?>
```

Here is my vb.net code:

```
            ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://sitename.com/verify.php")

            ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST"
            ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            Dim postData As String = "mac=45bgd0434"
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

            ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

            ' Get the request stream.
            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

            ' Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

            ' Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close()

            ' Get the response.
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()


            ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

            ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

            ' Read the content.
            Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()


            ' Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer)
```

I would just like to have only the output and not that extra code. Is there any way I can use an alternative method to print in PHP, or probably another method with which I can talk to the server?
I have tried other free servers on the internet, but they all seem to put in some code. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no such thing as a free lunch (RAH). Best is to contact your "free" hoster and ask them to remove the additional stuff. Consider, you could be trying to return some json with your php script.

Comment: Thank you, YvesLeBorg. Appreciate it.